# Prevent npm API call from outputting errors

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using the npm API to detect globally installed packages on the user's system so I can load extensions to my CLI program.

Unfortunately, when the below code runs, npm spews a ton of **`npm WARN unmet dependency`** messages out to my console. **Is it possible to prevent this?**

```
var npm = require('npm'),
    _ = require('lodash');

npm.load([], function(){
  npm.config.set('global', true);
  npm.commands.list(['--depth=0'], true, function(err, pkg){
    console.log(_.keys(pkg._dependencies).join('\n'));
  });
});
```

I've tried `npm.config.set('loglevel','silent')` and `npm.config.set('logstream',null)`; neither had any effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the `npm` api, can you just invoke the `npm` command?

`npm list -g --json --silent --depth 1`

produces a json-formatted list of global modules, with no output to stderr.